# CriteriaBuilder Instant to postgres TIMESTAMP conversion

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a Postrges DB table that has a column `created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE`.
In this table, there is a record with the timestamp `2020-02-15 00:00:00`. 
In the hibernate entity this field is mapped as follows:

```
@Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
private Instant createdAt;
```

And I'm trying to query the records using `CriteriaAPI`. I form the query in this way:

```
criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(rootEntity.get("created_at"), Instant.ofEpochSecond(1581724800L).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS))
```

The number `1581724800L` corresponds to `2020-02-15 00:00:00`, so it should work. However, this query does not return the record that I'm looking for.
Taking a look into the DB logs, I found that actually it queries for the timestamp `2020-02-15 03:00:00`. So, even though I'm using `Instant` and the DB field is `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE` in the query it converts the timestamp to the zoned one.

What could be the issue and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: could it be a timezone problem? It looks like hibernate somehow changes the time and shifts to a different timezone. Maybe try to set it to UTC `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC` or try to set a different timezone and see if the time in the query also changes

Comment: It's definitely a timezone problem since I'm in UTC+3 timezone. With this property this does work. And I'm a bit confused since I'm using `Instant` which is without a timezone, the DB column is without a timezone. Please, make the comment as an answer so I will accept it. And I will be very thankful if you could explain why does it happen.

Comment: I also don't know why or where it exactly happens (somewhere in hibernate is my guess), but I just had the same problem, so it sounded familiar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like hibernate somehow changes the time and shifts to a different timezone. Maybe try to set it to UTC `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC` or try to set a different timezone and see if the time in the query also changes